# Pass data from a form to a tab in Ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I can't figure out how can i pass data from a login page form to a tab in Ionic. This is my code that holds the data and should push it to the tabs, but it doesn't work.

**Login Page**

```
export class LoginPage {
  private login : FormGroup;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.login = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
  goToVoti(){
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsControllerPage, {
    username: this.login.value.username,
    password: this.login.value.password});
  }
}
```

Do i have to pass the data to the TabsController first and then to the desired page(s)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i have to pass login data i decided to store them locally, so i used IonicStorage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

This is what i did:

1. I stored the data from the login form:

   ```
   setData(){
   this.storage.set('username', this.login.value.username)
   this.storage.set('password', this.login.value.password)
   console.log('Data set')
   }
   ```

   And then i called this function inside goToVoti()
2. I retrieved the data in the other page when page loads:

   ```
   ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log("Data loaded");
   this.storage.get('username').then((val: string) => {
       console.log(val)
       this.email = val
     });
   this.storage.get('password').then((val: string) => {
       this.password = val
       console.log(val)
     });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From `Ionic Documentation`:

```
class StartPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  pushPage(){
    // push another page onto the navigation stack
    // causing the nav controller to transition to the new page
    // optional data can also be passed to the pushed page.
    this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage, {
      id: "123",
      name: "Carl"
    });
  }
}

class OtherPage {
  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
     let id = navParams.get('id');
     let name = navParams.get('name');
  }
}
```

Tabs example:

```
class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  pushData = () => {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage, {
      username: 'Marko',
      lastname: 'Savic',
    })
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(1);
  }

}

class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
    let username = navParams.get('username');
    let lastname = navParams.get('lastname');

    console.log(username);
    console.log(lastname);
  }
}
```

*Username* and *Lastname* are visible on *About Page*.

More about NavController [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found this: http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170505-PassingDataBetweenTabsInIonic2.html

Comment: I found another solution, thanks for the help anyway!